# Getting array of vertices using Lib3ds

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the vertices out of a file parsed by lib3ds and I'm having a lot of issues. Namely I'm not getting the vertices I was out. The code where I try to do this is:

```
//loop through meshes
for(int i = 0; i < model->meshes_size; i++)
{
    Lib3dsMesh* mesh = model->meshes[i];
    //loop through the faces in that mesh
    for(int j = 0; j < model->meshes[i]->nfaces; j++)
    {
        int testv = mesh->nvertices;
        Lib3dsFace face = mesh->faces[i];
        //loop through the vertices in each face
        for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            myVertices[index] = model->meshes[i]->faces[j].index[0];
            myVertices[index + 1] = model->meshes[i]->faces[j].index[1];
            myVertices[index + 2] = model->meshes[i]->faces[j].index[2];

            index += 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the documentation for lib3ds is non-existent and so I can't figure this out. How do you go about getting an array of vertices using this library? Also I'm aware that 3ds is old but the format and the way the library is set up suits my purpose so please don't suggest switching to another format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone has this issue, here is the code to get the vertices from lib3ds and then load them into a single array of vertices. The array just contains the data in the form x, y, z, x2, y2, z2 etc.

```
void Renderer3ds::loadVertices(string fileName)
{
    Lib3dsFile* model = lib3ds_file_open(fileName.c_str());

    if(!model)
    {
        throw strcat("Unable to load ", fileName.c_str());
    }

    int faces = getNumFaces(model);
    myNumVertices = faces * 3;
    myVertices = new double[myNumVertices * 3];

    int index = 0;

    //loop through meshes
    for(int i = 0; i < model->meshes_size; i++)
    {
        Lib3dsMesh* mesh = model->meshes[i];
        //loop through the faces in that mesh
        for(int j = 0; j < mesh->nfaces; j++)
        {
            Lib3dsFace face = mesh->faces[j];
            //loop through the vertices in each face
            for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                myVertices[index] = mesh->vertices[face.index[k]][0];
                myVertices[index + 1] = mesh->vertices[face.index[k]][1];
                myVertices[index + 2] = mesh->vertices[face.index[k]][2];

                index += 3;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit request: Change meshes_size to nmeshes because this is what the author meant in this context.

Comment: Is that also a field of Lib3dsFile?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familar with this topic but it was an anonymous edit. I knew it would get rejected so I thought I'd let future visitors of this thread know about it never the less.